# Speed up array merge calculations with cython

Tags: numpy

It's a simple job to combine a large array by different weights, which takes a lot of time, and I wanted to use Cython to provide better acceleration, so I wrote the following function, but found that it didn't get a performance boost, even slower than the numpy version, I want to know what the problem is? Thank you

cython version:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.math cimport fabs

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def merge(const float[:, ::1] pop, const float[:, :, ::1] dat):

    cdef Py_ssize_t pop_row = pop.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t pop_col = pop.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t dat_row = dat.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t dat_col = dat.shape[2]

    out = np.ones((pop_row, dat_row, dat_col), dtype = np.float32)
    cdef float[:, :, ::1] out_view = out

    cdef float tmp, fv, p, w
    cdef Py_ssize_t pi, fi, xi, yi

    for pi in prange(pop_row, nogil=True): 
        for fi in range(pop_col):      
            for xi in range(dat_row):    
                for yi in range(dat_col):
                    fv = dat[fi, xi, yi]
                    out_view[pi, xi, yi] *= fv * pop[pi, fi] + 1 
    return out
```

numpy version:

```
def numpy_merge(pop,dat):
    shap = list(dat.shape); shap[0] = len(pop)
    outs = np.full(shap, 1, dtype = dat.dtype) 
    for i, p in enumerate(pop):
        for x in np.where(p)[0]: 
            outs[i] *= dat[x] * p[x] + 1 
    outs -= 1
    return outs
```

test:

```
pop = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(100,100)).astype(np.float32)
dat = np.random.uniform( 0,1,size=(100,100,1000)).astype(np.float32)

%timeit merge(pop, dat)
%timeit numpy_merge(pop,dat)
```

## 2.73 s ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

## 1.16 s ± 8.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: It looks like a compiler problem. eg. `%%cython --compile-args=/openmp --compile-args=/O3 --compile-args=/ARCH:AVX2 --link-args=/openmp` on Windows 10 gives about 400ms, while a equivalent Numba version takes only 90ms. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Thank you, using the settings you provide has improved a lot, not much from the numpy version.

1.07 s ± 22.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.18 s ± 8.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Numba might be a good idea.